# PostGIS Group By Error

Tags: qgis, postgis, query

I am performing a pretty simple query in PostGIS 2.1.1 from within QGIS 2.2 for Windows (using  the DB Manager plugin). I have a table with many columns and I am trying to perform a Group By function. However, PostGIS returns an error when I do not add all the columns from my SELECT call within the GROUP BY call (see below).

**ORIGINAL QUERY**

```
SELECT city, state, city_abbr
FROM "public".footprints
WHERE city_abbr = 'nyc'
GROUP BY city
```

This query returns the following error:

```
column "footprints.state" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate      function
LINE 1: SELECT city, state, city_abbr
```

If I change my query to the following, it runs.

**ALTERED QUERY**

```
SELECT city, state, city_abbr
FROM "public".footprints
WHERE city_abbr = 'nyc'
GROUP BY city, state, city_abbr
```

I do not want to have to add each column to my GROUP BY statement. Can anyone shed any light on why this would be happening.

Thanks...

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the data in the table

```
gid   | city      | state   | city_abbr
______________________________________
0        boston      ny         bos
1        manhattan   ny         nyc
2        brooklyn    ny         nyc
3        newark      nj         nyc
4        denver      co         den
5        seattle     wa         sea
```

Comment: What do you want to calculate per-city? Your current queries are basically just no-ops. "Tell me every city." Is that what you want? "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM footprints" is a more correct way to get that.

Comment: It would help if you described the columns and their contents, so we wouldn't have to guess what they might contain.

Comment: When I perform a similar query in Spatialite I do not see this issue. What I am looking for is all the city names that have a city_abbr of nyc. I want to make sure I only get one return if there are cities that share the same city name. I understand distinct will give me this result, but I don't understand why GROUP BY needs to have all the columns that are identified in the SELECT.

Comment: Seems like a general Postgres question to me rather than anything PostGIS or QGIS specific.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what GROUP BY is for. I wrote an answer to that effect, but you closed and accepted the answer below before I could post it.

Comment: That's right, you do not see the issue with Spatialite. It runs the query without an error the result is rather arbitrary. Let's say there is A-A, A-B and A-C, but using GROUP BY A lists only one row in the resultset, A-A.

Comment: Right, SQLite's loosey goosey behavior in this case is a bug, not a feature.

Comment: If discussing SQL is forbidden in PostGIS topics, there will be a lot of orphan questions.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I didn't know you were filling something in. If you want to add the answer back up, I am sure others would find it useful. I do understand the meaning of GROUP BY; this example doesn't properly show my example. But thank you for your help.

Comment: @PaulRamsey all PostGIS-speciifc questions are welcome here. As I wrote, I think this is a general Postgres SQL question rather than a PostGIS question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769361/postgresql-group-by-different-from-mysql) from Stack Overflow, in particular the first comment, which states

> Postgres 9.1 allows to not list all columns if their table's primary key is part of the group by clause

So your query could be changed to (assuming primary key is uid):

```
SELECT city, state, city_abbr
FROM "public".footprints
WHERE city_abbr = 'nyc'
GROUP BY city,uid
```

And I believe it shouldn't balk at you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you have any idea why it would need a uid / gid? I haven't needed to do this with other databases.

Comment: You'll also get one row per footprint, which hardly seems like the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I feel also that you are misusing GROUG BY as Paul R. said.